# I lose the pretty colouring on my code when I use optional chaining

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Can anyone tell me why I am losing the code formatting when I use optional chaining in my JSX? There is no error thrown and the code runs, it just doesn't like it.

[image: Shows div tags not highlighted in the correct colour]

As shown above, everything after the brackets is now blue where it should be red.
Currently using up to date create-react-app, ESLint, prettier and using VSCode as my development environment.

Comment: Probably a good question to ask Microsoft.

Comment: Exactly the same happens here with spans in snippets

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it - An extension was interfering with the formatting, disabling it fixed the issue.

The extension was Babel ES6/ES7 by dzannotti.

Comment: You should say which extension it was to help other people.

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall whatever babel extensions you have and instead install this extension.

[Babel JavaScript](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel)
[image: Screenshot of extension]